# PowerPoint 2003 hangs on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2003, windows-10-v21h2

In Windows 10 21H2, PowerPoint 2003(both RTM and SP3) hangs when touch the title bar.(I mean, like when dragging the window, pressing close/maximize/minimize)(Before, it also hanged right after launching) I reinstalled several times but it did not help, it happens in both Ofiice 2007 compatibility pack installed and not installed.

I tried to Reinstall it several times, try installing/uninstalling updates.

I Also tried to set Compatibility mode but it does not work.

It should not hang and work properly.

Excel & Word 2003 works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Office 2003 is very long out of support. So if Power Point is not working on Windows 10 (a) no surprise and (b) no fixes.  Remember that Power Point is the most complicated of Excel, Word and Power Point.

So you have two options:

(1) Run Office 2003 in a virtual machine. I do this and it works fine.

(2) Upgrade your Office suite. I have done this as well.

I have tried other Office Suites and I do not like them as well as Office itself. So I stick with Office.

Comment: Third option: try free LibreOffice, which includes *Impress*, very similar software to *Power:Point*, and which can load, edit and run most *Power:Point* presentations.